# Firestore: How to add a document to a subcollection after updating parent

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building out a quick API for an IOT type app. The structure is that I have a sensor document with *latestValue1* and *latestVoltage* values. Each sensor document also has a collection of readings (an hourly log, let's say.)

The Set function works fine to update *latestValue1* and *latestVoltage*, but I'm struggling to work out how to create the readings collection and add a document to it- the code below gives me ***TypeError: document.collection is not a function***

```
app.put('/api/update/:item_id', (req, res) => {
    (async () => {
        try {
            const document = db.collection('sensors').doc(req.params.item_id).set({
                latestValue1: req.body.value1,
                latestVoltage: req.body.voltage
            }, {merge: true});
            await document.collection('readings').add({
                value1: req.body.value1,
                voltage: req.body.voltage
            });
            return res.status(200).send();
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            return res.status(500).send(error);
        }
    })();
});
```

How can I fix the code above to correctly add a new document to the readings collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`set()` doesn't return a DocumentReference object.  It returns a promise which you should await.

```
await db.collection('sensors').doc(req.params.item_id).set({
    latestValue1: req.body.value1,
    latestVoltage: req.body.voltage
}, {merge: true});
```

If you want to build a reference to a subcollection, you should chain calls to get there.  `add()` also returns a promise that you should await.

```
await db.collection('sensors').doc(req.params.item_id)collection('readings').add({
    value1: req.body.value1,
    voltage: req.body.voltage
});
```

FYI you can also declare the entire express handler function async to avoid the inner anonymous async function:

```
app.put('/api/update/:item_id', async (req, res) => {
    // await in here
});
```