# Firebase: update document by ID stored in body

Tags: firebase

I'm building a simple Firebase API to update a simple value. I'm sending a PUT request to the url *appname.cloudfunctions.net/app/api/update/* with the ID of the document to be updated in the body:

```
{
    "id": 10,
    "value1": 11
}
```

And then my function looks like this:

```
app.put('/api/update/', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const sensorId = req.body.id;
        await db.collection('sensors').doc(sensorId).set({
            latestUpdateTimestamp: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
            latestValue1: req.body.value1,
        }, {merge: true});
        return res.status(200).send();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        console.log(req.body);
        return res.status(500).send(error);
    }
});
```

Problem is, I get an error: *Error: Value for argument "documentPath" is not a valid resource path. Path must be a non-empty string.* Note that *console.log(req.body)* shows the correct ID & value1 from the body.

How can I fix that?

Comment: Try `console.log(req.body)` and see what shows up -- that error indicates that `req.body.id` is `undefined`.

Comment: Yeah that works fine, the ID is showing in there. If it helps, this is a slight modification from code from another question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64779618/firestore-how-to-add-a-document-to-a-subcollection-after-updating-parent/64780008#64780008

Comment: It says `Path must be a non-empty string` but `"id": 10`. Could that be why?

Comment: @windowsill cheers yeah it's solved now, had to add .toString()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My const *sensorId* was being sent as a number, I needed to change it to a string to get it to work:

`const sensorId = req.body.id.toString();`